# How to install JWT authentication in ktor and the JWT token is created by firebase authentication system

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, ktor

I am using firebase token to verify my https call s to my ktor server. How can I install jwt authentication in ktor to verify the token? Now I am using a custom jwt and install authentication like given below

```
    install(Authentication) {
    jwt {
        verifier(myJWT.verifier)
        validate {
            UserIdPrincipal(it.payload.getClaim("key").asString())
        }
      }
    }
```

But when I am using firebase token I don't have an issuer. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How do you link the request to firebase? Retrieve the token and validate it in ktor.

Comment: which request are you talking about?

Comment: Incoming requests to your server. Anyway, the process is simple. Obtain your token from firebase and then validate it in ktor.